# Nodejs - How to schedule to send email

Tags: node.js, cron, jobs, schedule

In MYSQL I have a table named scheduler_working
has columns id, startTime (DateTime data type), and email

Now how in nodejs I want to send an email if starTime is equal to system time. I want to schedule it to run once at a time maybe after 1 or more hours instead of having to continuously scan the scheduler_working table every minute and then match the time in the starTime column to the current system time. Because this method will waste server resources because the scheduler_working table will likely have millions of records

Many thanks and HPNW!

Answer (score 0):

```
const nodeSchedule = require('node-schedule');
const job = nodeSchedule.scheduleJob('* * * * *', function(){
    console.log('Job has been triggered at: ', new Date.toLocaleTimeString());
})
```

*Use this code to trigger you scheduler according to your time interval use common time like every 10 min
Use reddis for fetching data for your email schedule time*